# mongodb 4.0 transactions support for node.js

Tags: mongodb

cannot find documentation for mongodb 4.0 transactions support for node.js

Has it already been available in mongo driver 
http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/

Comment: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/ClientSession.html#startTransaction

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned on the comment as well, you can find the reference for transactions on [node-mongodb-native v3.1 API ClientSession](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/ClientSession.html#startTransaction). This is because transactions are associated with a session. That is, you start a transaction for a session. At any given time, you can have at most one open transaction for a session.

The documentation for [MongoDB multi-document Transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/) also contains examples `Node.js` code snippets. For example:

```
  session.startTransaction({
    readConcern: { level: 'snapshot' },
    writeConcern: { w: 'majority' }
  });

  const employeesCollection = client.db('hr').collection('employees');
  const eventsCollection = client.db('reporting').collection('events');

  await employeesCollection.updateOne(
    { employee: 3 },
    { $set: { status: 'Inactive' } },
    { session }
  );
  await eventsCollection.insertOne(
    {
      employee: 3,
      status: { new: 'Inactive', old: 'Active' }
    },
    { session }
  );

  try {
    await commitWithRetry(session);
  } catch (error) {
    await session.abortTransaction();
    throw error;
  }
```

The reference for the methods above can be found on:

- [ClientSession.startTransaction()](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/ClientSession.html#startTransaction)
- [ClientSession.commitTransaction()](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/ClientSession.html#commitTransaction)
- [ClientSession.abortTransaction()](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/ClientSession.html#abortTransaction)

In addition to MongoDB Node.js driver v3.1, please note that multi-document transactions are available for **replica sets** only on MongoDB v4.0.x. Transactions for sharded clusters are available starting with version v4.2.