# MongoDB transaction vs firebase transaction

Tags: node.js, mongodb

**Question1:**

Is mongoDB transaction available in Nodejs? or is it only available for Python and Java at the moment?

Java

```
try (ClientSession clientSession = client.startSession()) {
   clientSession.startTransaction();
   collection.insertOne(clientSession, docOne);
   collection.insertOne(clientSession, docTwo);
   clientSession.commitTransaction();
}
```

Python

```
with client.start_session() as s:
    s.start_transaction()
    collection_one.insert_one(doc_one, session=s)
    collection_two.insert_one(doc_two, session=s)
    s.commit_transaction()
```

**Question2:**

If there are 2 users calling the same API at the same time updating the same document, will transaction solve the race condition. Where it will wait for the 1st process of user 1 reading and updating the document and only process the 2nd process of user 2 reading and updating the document?

Previously, when using firebase cloud function, I'm able to solve this issue using [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data). Not sure if it's the same thing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51587451/mongodb-4-0-transactions-support-for-node-js